# What are the benefits of upgrading a Stronghold?

Tags: mad-max

Early in the game, you unlock Strongholds, in which you can build various projects in order to gain benefits (such as refueling and rearming when visiting the base, or additional scrap when you destroy cars).

In Gutgash's Stronghold (and probably others), there is also the option to make a small / medium stockpile, which makes the Stronghold "better" for the cost of 500/1000.

How is the stronghold made better by adding these piles of scrap, or is it simply cosmetic?

Comment: Which improvement gives out additional scrap when destroying cars? The closest one I can think of is the cleanup crew project, but that only automatically collects scrap from destroyed cars.

Comment: @DangerZone: That's the only one that does that, I think. Though there is another that generates a small amount of scrap over time when you're offline. Seems fairly small amounts, though.

Comment: @Jeeva Yeah it is a small increase. But you can build them in multiple Strongholds which will multiply the small increase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than it being necessary for one of the achievements/trophies, the scrap pile upgrades are purely cosmetic.